# Change the names of the parameters posted to server in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

On submitting the edit form in jqgrid it post the entity-id as id=some_value. How I can change the name of the parameter from id to Id, that saves my life in ASP.NET MVC model binding at server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter to rename any jqGrid parameter. For example

```
prmNames: {id:'Id'}
```